# What are the differences between a OpenGL shader code written in a .cg file and another in a vsh/fsh file?

Tags: xcode, opengl-es, shader

I'm a **OpenGL ES 2.0** beginner and I don't understand why are **different types** of code for **shaders**. In particular, the differences between `.cg` and `.vsh` / `.fsh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Cg** is a shading language owned and operated by **NVIDIA**. **GLSL** is the shading language for **OpenGL**. **Cg** works by being compiled into some form of **GLSL**, based on a ["profile"](https://developer.nvidia.com/cg-profiles) that represents the **GLSL** version and shader stage type.

If you're using **OpenGL ES**, you should be ignoring **Cg**. You can't use **Cg** in **OpenGL ES**, because **ES**'s version of **GLSL** has requirements that **Cg** can't fulfill. So if you're seeing some tutorial using **Cg**, ignore it.

The extension names are entirely irrelevant. Use whatever extension is clearest to you; **OpenGL** doesn't read files, so it's up to you to feed shader strings to glView.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the **CG toolkit** of **Nvidia**, you typically use `.cg` as the file extension,
but if you are using the **GLSL shaders**, you could use `.vsh`, `.fsh`, `.frag`, `.vert` or `.glsl`.